# Switchable Graphics switching from Graphic Card to another

Tags: 11.10, ati, graphics

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and a switchable graphics Intel/ATI

After many and many troubles with proprietary drivers, I last uninstalled them to install the opensource alternative. But now my question is:

1. How to choiche what VGA to use?
2. How to know what one is use by Ubuntu?

I know that I can use vgaswitcheroo but I cannot find it on my installation?
Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: which computer/laptop model are we talking about?

Comment: hp dv7 laptop VGA graphics intel/ATI

Answer (score 3):

Arr dirty old switchable graphics are still a pain in the ars...

first, open a terminal and become root:

```
sudo su
```

check if there is a 'debug' directory in /sys/kernel/

if it's not, go and add this line to /etc/fstab

```
none                    /sys/kernel/debug debugfs defaults 0 0
```

(and reboot)

You should now see a debug directory in /sys/kernel
check if the vgaswitcheroo directory exists in /sys/kernel/debug

if not, make sure to use Intel and Ati Foss drivers ( not fglrx )

once you see the file /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch you're ready to party hard!

If you want to use the intel card, just paste in a terminal (as root)

```
echo DIGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

now log out and in again ( not rebootin'! ) -> welcome to the intel card's power

if you want to switch to the ati card, do same as above but paste this time

```
echo DDIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

and you're ready to fire more 3d performance up!

if your laptop's fan is always on, this might mean that both cards are activated.
as you're only using one at a time, we simply power the unused one off:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

you can always check wich card is currently running with this command

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

i want you to notice at this time, that the intel's and the foss ati driver's 3d-performances are ... well ... not actually that awesome. And the foss ati driver's powermanagement is just crap or no one ever implemented that i dunno...

if you desire full 3d performance and working powermanagement (you know, there is a difference between having 2h of batterylife or 6h ..)  you can still try to fight with fglrx ( ati's propetary driver ). Once you made it working with fglrx, you can simply switch graphic cards via the ati catalyst control center ( including re-logins ). But fglrx is a tricky *** ... i might be a long dark path to success - if it's ever working on one's machine ...

however, check this site for more details about switchin' with foss drivers and vgaswitcheroo:
http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com/